# Generate a few models from existing database in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I know this exists

```
django-admin.py inspectdb > models.py
```

However, is there an easy way to limit it? Without manually deleting what I don't want.

I'm connecting to a database that has over one hundred tables, but I only want models of about 4 or 5. Is there an easy way to generate models from a few given tables?

They are quite big tables, so I don't fancy typing them all out either.

Comment: Checked the source of Django 1.1 and didn't find a way to do this. Depending on your database engine, you maybe able to restrict the tables that Django sees or simply create a dummy database with the schemas of the tables that you want to inspect.

Comment: Its an Oracle database - not sure how I'd restrict the tables it sees though?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the permissions system in Oracle, so I don't know. What about the second idea? It should be pretty easy to recreate the schemas of those 4-5 tables in a separate database.

Comment: It probably would be easy to recreate the schemas, but it seems like some hassle I don't want to go through. I just inspected the db and manually deleted the extra models this morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did this myself, also with Oracle. It's possible - but not pretty.

Assuming you know the names of the tables you want -

open `django/db/backends/oracle/introspection.py`. There is a function `get_table_list`:

```
def get_table_list(self, cursor):
    "Returns a list of table names in the current database."
    cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES")
    return [row[0].lower() for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Just replace it with something like

```
def get_table_list(self, cursor):
    names = ['mytable1', 'mytable2', 'mytable3']
    return names
```

Then run your `inspectdb` and it will be a lot more managable :)

Comment: newer version of Django:


def get_table_list(self, cursor):
        names = [
            TableInfo('table1', 't'),
            TableInfo('table_2', 't'),
            .....
        ]
        return names

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `syncdb > models.py`. It's not a good practice. Make your models manually and add `managed=False` to it. If you will not add it your all database tables can be deleted via single command. After creating your models then run the `syncdb` so that tables are linked.

Comment: Surely good practice would just be to check models.py afterwards? Typing everything out would just be tedious

Answer (score 0):

Following solution given by @pfctdayelise

For `django 1.8` mysql backend

open `django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py` and find function `get_table_list`:

```
def get_table_list(self, cursor):
    cursor.execute("SHOW FULL TABLES")
    return [TableInfo(row[0], {'BASE TABLE': 't', 'VIEW': 'v'}.get(row[1]))
            for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Replace it with something like

```
def get_table_list(self, cursor):
    names = [TableInfo('mytable1', 't')]
    return names
```

To decide whether the second argument to `TableInfo` is `t` or `v`, run the mysql query `SHOW FULL TABLES` and find out your `table_type` if it is a `BASE_TABLE` then second argument is `t` else `v`

Then run

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Django 1.10, the inspectdb command takes an optional list of tables on the command line that limits which tables will be inspected.